DISM /Cleanup-Image actual documentation
Where is actually DISM /Cleanup-Image documented?
DISM /Cleanup-Image is mentioned in different pages e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image?view=windows-10.
But neither DISM /? (Version: 10.0.19041.1) nor DISM Image Management Command-Line Options show the option /Cleanup-Image.

Does this answer your question? What is the purpose of the DISM /RestoreHealth parameter and SFC?

Since /Cleanup-Image is used for servicing the Component Store  [%WinDir%\WinSxS], which is used both to store previous versions of updated components [Windows Update] and for repairing Windows, it's covered in different man pages depending on the use case.

Online image servicing is for a booted to %SystemDrive%, whereas offline image servicing is for a non-booted to %SystemDrive%, ESD, FFU, or WIM, and the online or offline state of an image will determine the second parameter of:
Dism </Online | /Image:> /Cleanup-Image /?


/Online  services a %SystemDrive% while booted to it
/Image:  path to the Windows or Windows\WinSxS directory of a non-booted to %SystemDrive%, or a directory containing a mounted ESD/WIM/FFU [C:\Mount] 




Dism [Deployment Image Servicing and Management], and it's command line options, do a myriad of things as the backbone of Windows image management and servicing, and depending on what Dism is being used for will determine the man page referenced:

Package Servicing: services the Component Store
Image Management:  services an online/offline image (%SystemDrive%, ESD, FFU, WIM), or captures, applies, and/or modifies an ESD, WIM, or FFU

File Formats:

ESD / WIM:  Encrypted Software Distribution / Windows IMage 
FFU:  Full Flash Update






Cleanup-Image is more like the name of the tool that you are telling
DISM to use. It just means that you're intending to do clean and recover
operations on the system.
It's the switches after Cleanup-Image that tell DISM how to use the
Cleanup-Image tool.
